# php $this->view->$someVar is it possible?

Tags: php, oop, variable-assignment

I'm create a model view controller framework and im kind of new to this. I want to pass variables from controllers to views. My View.php constructor looks like this:

```
    function __construct($file, $args) {
        $this->view = $file;
         foreach($args as $key => $arg) {
            $this->view->$key = 'awda';
         }
    }
```

it gives me error cause

```
 $this->view->$key is not a valid statement.
```

If i do it from Controller something like

```
 $this->view->hello = 'hello world'
```

and i do echo

```
 $this->hello
```

in view it works fine, but i want to be able to have multiple vars passed in. Does anyone know a better way of doing this? thank you

Comment: `$this->view->{$key}` should work

Comment: now i get Warning: Attempt to assign property of non-object in  this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to assign properties to what I suspect is a string (`$file`). Since you are inside your view's constructor, you can simply use `$this` to refer to the view:

```
function __construct($file, $args) {
    $this->view = $file;
     foreach($args as $key => $arg) {
        $this->view->$key = 'awda'; // HERE is the issue.. isn't $this->view a string?
     }
}


function __construct($file, $args) {
    $this->view = $file;
     foreach($args as $key => $arg) {
        $this->$key = 'awda'; // assign $key as property of $this instead...
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you just saved my another 1 hour of staring at my code and trying to figure out things. :) thanks alot, now it worked